# justifyContent: 'flex-end' não alinha na base

Tags: react, react-native, flexbox

Estou tentando adicionar uma barra com valor do produto na parte inferior da aplicação, utilizando o `justifyContent: 'flex-end'` porém o conteúdo não desce, fica colado na View que vem acima. O código é esse

```
    const ItemDetalhe = props => {
        return (
            <View style={estilos.conteudo}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Image style={estilos.fotoCabecalho} source={{ uri: props.fotoProduto }} />
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={estilos.txtTitulo}>{props.tituloProduto}</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={estilos.txtDescricao}>{props.descricaoProduto}</Text>
                    </View>


    // ---->> Estou tentando jogar essa view para a parte mais baixa da aplicação

                    <View style={estilos.containerValor}>
                        <Text style={estilos.txtValor}>R${props.valorProduto}</Text>
                    </View>



                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    const estilos = StyleSheet.create({
        conteudo: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            flex: 1
        },
        fotoCabecalho: {
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
        },
        txtTitulo: {
            fontSize: 30,
            color: 'black',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center'

        },
        txtDescricao: {
            fontSize: 20,
            color: 'black',
            textAlign: 'center'

        },    
        txtValor: {
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: 40
        },
        containerValor: {
            backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',

        }
    });
```

O trecho que estou tentando descer é o que contem o containerValor

Comment: Renan não foi eu que dei o negativo. Mas vou te dar uma dica! Coloque o código já renderizado no browser. Então abre a view no navegador e da um Ctrl+U para pegar o código já compilado no browser. Ai fica mais fácil para alguém te ajudar. Se possível coloca o CSS normal tb e não como vc colocou. Isso vai amentar a chance de alguém te ajudar. Pois da forma que está a maioria aqui não vai conseguir simular o problema que vc está tendo ai

Comment: Acredito que a aplicação que ele se refere seja um aplicativo react-native. @Renan Bicudo Ferrari poderia confirmar?